# Оптимизация скорости загрузки сайта, в режиме 3g не до конца загружается страница

Tags: javascript, css, pagespeed-insights

Есть лендинг, сделанный на Adobe Muse https://sib.meistercompany.ru/.

Проблема заключается в том, что при эмулировании загрузки в режиме Slow 3g или реальном заходе с медленным интернетом сайт просто не загружается до конца едет верстка и он становится не презентабельным.

Насколько получилось разобраться адаптивный режим строится при помощи js.

Основная задача была оптимизировать скорость загрузки, но в процессе нашли эту проблему

Может у кого была схожая ситуация и можете подсказать в чем может быть дело?

Comment: у меня он совсем не открывается. Так что да, на телефоне оно точно не будет прогружаться до конца. Ну и конечно не стоит забывать о https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/muse/kb/adobe-muse-end-of-service.html

Comment: проблема с хостингом, да, я могу написать, как заработает. Про поддержку разумеется знаем, но не мы разработчики, наша задача оптимизировать скорость

Comment: можете вот тут глянуть, та ссылка на тестовой домен, но разницы нет https://сибэкоинжиниринг.рф/

Comment: прикольно, когда не разработчики пытаются пофиксить то, что натворили разработчики. Я как минимум вижу файл шрифтов, который достаточно большой и я попробовал бы от него отказаться. и от muse. Но это все работа разработчиков.

Comment: файлов шрифтов было 6, оставили 3. Но ещё раз проблема основная не в этом, а в том, что при медленном интернете не загружается.

Comment: А Вы в логи сервера посмотрите, может оно обрубает по тайм-ауту. Больше 30 секунд - отключили

Comment: У Вас там картинок на 2.5МБ, для slow 3g это ооочень много. В основном это сертификаты и грамоты в большом разрешении, их уменьшить можно раза в 3, они даже в экран не влазят. По хорошему надо добавить inline критических CSS а не грузить полностью большой файл, и подлнимите index.css с низа страницы в head. Плюс с muse.js разобраться, он на пол секунды блочит поток. Jquery скопируйте локально, а не подгружайте со стороннего сайта. Весь js с метриками скиньте вниз страницы.

Comment: Хостер дал вот такой ответ: Провел проверку, ошибка воспроизводится, однако все статические файлы отдаются с успешным кодом 200. Если бы запросы убивались по таймауту, то вам бы отдавалась ошибка 502. Изображения грузятся, но это вопрос времени ответа, а не закрытия соединения со стороны сервера.

Хочу обратить ваше внимание, что мод Slow 3G является серьезным стресс-тестом для любого сайта. Однако все равно сфомировал отчет Lighthouse по производительности. Фреймворк не использует задержки, которые используются при Slow 3G, но результаты все равно показывают....